# Why this commandLink never calls the action inside the PageBlockTable.?

Tags: visualforce, commandlink

I have an issue with a CommandLink that is inside a PageBlockTable, the action's CommandLink is never called inside the PageBlockTable, but outside the method is called properly from the same CommandLink.

This is the VF Code

```
<apex:page standardController="pba__Property__c" extensions="PaquetesDisponiblesExtension">
    <style>
      .link{
        //text-decoration: underline;
        //text-color:#99BBE8;
        //cursor:pointer;
      }
    </style>
     <apex:form >
                    <apex:commandLink value="Utilizar" action="{!utilizarPaquete}"  styleClass="link">
                    <apex:param name="paqueteId" value="{!paqueteAct}" assignTo="{!paqueteUtilizado}"/>
                    <apex:param name="casaId" value="{!casaEnPaqueteActual}" assignTo="{!casaEnPaqueteActual}"/>
                    <apex:param name="solicitud" value="{!solicitudEnPaqueteActual}" assignTo="{!solicitudEnPaqueteActual}"/>
                </apex:commandLink>
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!obtenerPaquetesRelacionadosDisponibles}" var="paquete">
               <apex:column ><apex:commandLink value="Utilizar" action="{!utilizarPaquete}">
                    <apex:param name="paqueteUtilizado" value="{!paquete.Id}" assignTo="{!paqueteUtilizado}"/>
                    <apex:param name="casaEnPaqueteActual" value="{!casaEnPaqueteActual}" assignTo="{!casaEnPaqueteActual}"/>
                    <apex:param name="casaEnPaqueteActual" value="{!solicitudEnPaqueteActual}" assignTo="{!solicitudEnPaqueteActual}"/>
                </apex:commandLink></apex:column>

            <apex:column value="{!paquete.Name}" />
            <apex:column value="{!paquete.Paquete_Fraccionamiento_paquete__c}" />
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

And Here is the extension:

```
public with sharing class PaquetesDisponiblesExtension {


    public static ApexPages.StandardController stdCtrl{get; set;}

    public static Id paqueteUtilizado {get; set;}
    public  static String nombrePaqueteActual {get; set;}
    public  static Id casaEnPaqueteActual {get; set;}
    public  static Id solicitudEnPaqueteActual  {get; set;}

    public static Id paqueteAct {get; set;}

    // Metodo Constructor
    public PaquetesDisponiblesExtension(ApexPages.StandardController std) {
        stdCtrl = std;
        informacionPaqueteActual();
    }

    // Informacion del paquete actual que se pasara al paquete seleccionado
    // de la lista (VSF PaquetesDisponibles)
    public static void informacionPaqueteActual() {        
       System.debug('Informacion Paquetes Actual==>'+stdCtrl.getId());
       for(pba__Property__c paquete : [Select Id, Sol_de_Compra_paquete__c, Paquete_casa__c,
                             Paquete_Fraccionamiento_paquete__c
                             From pba__Property__c Where Id =: stdCtrl.getId()]){

               System.debug('Paquete Actual ==>'+paquete);    
               // Obtener el Nombre, Solicitud y Casa del paquete
               nombrePaqueteActual = paquete.Paquete_Fraccionamiento_paquete__c;
               casaEnPaqueteActual = paquete.Paquete_casa__c;
               solicitudEnPaqueteActual = paquete.Sol_de_Compra_paquete__c;
       }

    }

    // Envia los paquetes relacionados con el paquete que esta siendo
    // actualmente visto
    public List<pba__Property__c>obtenerPaquetesRelacionadosDisponibles {

        get{
            List<pba__Property__c> paquetesRelacionados = new List<pba__Property__c>();
            for (pba__Property__c paquete : [Select Id, Name, Paquete_Fraccionamiento_paquete__c  
                                                From pba__Property__c Where RecordType.Name = 'Paquete' 
                                                And Paquete_Fraccionamiento_paquete__c =: nombrePaqueteActual
                                                And Sol_de_Compra_paquete__c = null And Paquete_casa__c = null
                                                And Paquete_Estatus_de_instalacion__c = 'En Inventario']) {
                    paquetesRelacionados.add(paquete);

                    // Just for testing
                    paqueteAct = paquete.Id;
            }

            return paquetesRelacionados;
        }
        private set;
    }


    public PageReference utilizarPaquete() {

        System.debug('Entre aqui ==>'+paqueteUtilizado);
        pba__Property__c actualizarPaquete = new pba__Property__c(
                Id = paqueteUtilizado,
                Paquete_casa__c = casaEnPaqueteActual,
                Sol_de_Compra_paquete__c = solicitudEnPaqueteActual
        );

        System.debug('ActualizarPaquete ==>'+actualizarPaquete);
        pba__Property__c eliminarPaquete = new pba__Property__c();
        //eliminarPaquete = (pba__Property__c)stdCtrl.getRecord();

        SavePoint sp = Database.setSavePoint();

        try {
          update actualizarPaquete;
          //delete eliminarPaquete;
        } catch (DmlException e) {
            ApexPages.addMessages(e);
            System.debug('Error en actualizar Paquete ==>'+actualizarPaquete+e.getMessage());
            Database.rollback(sp);
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Code seems fine. There is no error in it.

Comment: are you having issues with Param not being passed to controller, or issue with the commandlink

Comment: The issue is with the commmandLink, it has an action that is never called when I click the link inside the PageBlockTable section, but if i put the same commandLink code outside that table, it works correctly.

Comment: odd, I use this construction all the time and it works. Only difference I see in my code is presence of `headerValue="string"` as part of `apex:column` and instance variables for my getters/setters rather than statics

Comment: Hi Guys. Thanks for your comments. I re-wrote my code to make it work. I'll show you what was my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling the method as an action I added an onclick event on a column and the JS function makes the trick. And I also made minor changes on the Extension.

VisualForce:

```
 <apex:page standardController="pba__Property__c" extensions="PaquetesDisponiblesExtension">
        <script src="../../soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="../../soap/ajax/29.0/apex.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <apex:includescript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.CP_jquery_min)}"/> 

        <style>
          .link{
            text-decoration: underline;
            cursor:pointer;
          }
        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript">
           // you have the option of assigning a new variable name to replace the $ alias
           var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

           $j(document).ready(function(){
                 // Inicializar en el header una sesion de salesforce valida
                 session = sforce.connection.session = "{!$Api.Session_ID}";
                 sforce.connection.init(session, '../../services/Soap/u/29.0');

                 // Casa y Solicitud del paquete donde se esta viendo la VSF PaquetesDisponibles
                 casa = "{!casaEnPaqueteActual}";
                 solicitud = "{!solicitudEnPaqueteActual}";
           });

          function llamarUtilizarPaquete(pq) {
             alert('Entre');
             // Llamar al metodo
             var result = sforce.apex.execute(
                 "PaquetesDisponiblesExtension",
                 "utilizarPaquete",{
                       paqueteId : pq,
                       casa : casa,
                       solicitud : solicitud
                 });

             alert('Result'+result);
             console.log('Error or Success: '+result);

          }
        </script>
       <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!obtenerPaquetesRelacionadosDisponibles}" var="paquete">
                <apex:column value="{!IF(NOT(ISBLANK(paquete.Id)),'Utilizar','Utilizar')} " onclick="llamarUtilizarPaquete('{!paquete.Id}')" styleClass="link"/>
                <apex:column value="{!paquete.Name}" />
                <apex:column value="{!paquete.Paquete_Fraccionamiento_paquete__c}" />
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
      </apex:form>
    </apex:page>
```

Extension:

```
global class PaquetesDisponiblesExtension {


    public static ApexPages.StandardController stdCtrl{get; set;}

    public static Id paqueteUtilizado {get; set;}
    public  static String nombrePaqueteActual {get; set;}
    public  static Id casaEnPaqueteActual {get; set;}
    public  static Id solicitudEnPaqueteActual  {get; set;}


    // Metodo Constructor
    public PaquetesDisponiblesExtension(ApexPages.StandardController std) {
        stdCtrl = std;
        informacionPaqueteActual();
    }

    // Informacion del paquete actual que se pasara al paquete seleccionado
    // de la lista (VSF PaquetesDisponibles)
    public static void informacionPaqueteActual() {        

       for(pba__Property__c paquete : [Select Id, Sol_de_Compra_paquete__c, Paquete_casa__c,
                             Paquete_Fraccionamiento_paquete__c
                             From pba__Property__c Where Id =: stdCtrl.getId()]){

               // Obtener el Nombre, Solicitud y Casa del paquete
               nombrePaqueteActual = paquete.Paquete_Fraccionamiento_paquete__c;
               casaEnPaqueteActual = paquete.Paquete_casa__c;
               solicitudEnPaqueteActual = paquete.Sol_de_Compra_paquete__c;
       }

    }

    // Envia los paquetes relacionados con el paquete que esta siendo
    // actualmente visto
    public List<pba__Property__c>obtenerPaquetesRelacionadosDisponibles {

        get{
            List<pba__Property__c> paquetesRelacionados = new List<pba__Property__c>();
            for (pba__Property__c paquete : [Select Id, Name, Paquete_Fraccionamiento_paquete__c  
                                                From pba__Property__c Where RecordType.Name = 'Paquete' 
                                                And Paquete_Fraccionamiento_paquete__c =: nombrePaqueteActual
                                                And Sol_de_Compra_paquete__c = null And Paquete_casa__c = null
                                                And Paquete_Estatus_de_instalacion__c = 'En Inventario']) {
                    paquetesRelacionados.add(paquete);
            }

            return paquetesRelacionados;
        }
        private set;
    }

    // TODO: add Comments
    webService static String utilizarPaquete(Id paqueteId,Id casa, Id solicitud) {
        pba__Property__c actualizarPaquete = new pba__Property__c(
                Id = paqueteId,
                Paquete_casa__c = casa,
                Sol_de_Compra_paquete__c = solicitud
        );

        System.debug('ActualizarPaquete ==>'+actualizarPaquete);
        pba__Property__c eliminarPaquete = new pba__Property__c();
        //eliminarPaquete = (pba__Property__c)stdCtrl.getRecord();

        SavePoint sp = Database.setSavePoint();

        try {
          update actualizarPaquete;
          //delete eliminarPaquete;
          return 'done';
        } catch (DmlException e) {
            System.debug('Error en actualizar Paquete ==>'+actualizarPaquete+e.getMessage());
            Database.rollback(sp);
            return e.getMessage();
        }
    }

}
```